# Unused Variable warning in Visual Studio Code (Python)

Tags: python, pylint

Why do I get unused variable warning in Visual Studio Code, when there quite clearly is a use - just 3 lines below the offending variable declaration?  Here the warning is given for variable

```
found_r_object_id_in_cara
```

the variable is referenced in an 'if' statement a few lines below the declaration.

[image]

Comment: a) don't post pictures of code b) do you USE the variable anywhere or just set it to a value and not touch it

Comment: You're getting the warning because the variable is unused i.e you don't you don't use the value - you just set it

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: I use it in an if statement on line 131

Comment: I added pictures to show the IDE identifying the unused variable

Answer (score 7):

Add these lines at the top of the program (Global declaration)

```
# pylint: disable=unused-variable
# pylint: enable=too-many-lines
```

This may help someone.

Comment: This is great. Now is there a way to do this in settings? I could not find it in vsc 1.49.2

Answer (score 5):

Are you using the variable in question after setting the value inside if loop, if not the warning is valid. Setting and unsetting without actual usage will generate warning. There are couple of ways to disable the warning ( although this one seems like legitimate).

you can put this above the line thats generating the warning:

```
#pylint: disable=unused-argument
```

Prefix the variable name with _ underscore